# Interview Presentation for Postdoc

Tags: postdocs, presentation

I have been asked to give a small presentation as a part of the postdoc interview. The general guideline is that the presentation should foster ideas, roles and vision in the upcoming project. Basically, I have discussed the scientific ideas concerning the project, however what could I add to make it even more effective?

Comment: What about the roles and the vision?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing anything about the specifics, good general advice often given to me is 'Present it to your mum / partner / dog'.

Our top professor gave feedback on a talk recently saying that he has seen many talks that are too complicated that he couldn't follow. He has never seen one that he thought was too simple. If you aim to make your presentations understandable by a lay audience, you'll probably hit about the right level of complexity for experienced researchers.

The worst thing possible is that you make it too technical and the panel don't understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score -3):

The presentation is supposed to be given to highly technical and professional people, not to lay audience. Your presentation should be full of technical knowledge and really impressive. It should reflect depth of your knowledge about the field and your potential.

Make the audience believe  that you are the best candidate for this project. You are not there to increase the knowledge of the audience but to get hired for a paid job.

Comment: I used to think this way when I was a PhD student. Now, I'd strongly advise against this line of thinking.